# MySQL Data Filter Without Group By

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

I have created database for my checmical experiments rather than using Excel. I'm filling a HTML form and a php function making some calculations with that data, then insert them to MySQL database table named **exp**. I don't want to bore you with details. Table design of **exp** is like that;

### [image: example table]

**Exp ID** is the experiment number and **Product** is for sample taken by in this experiment. Result

What I'm trying to do is filtering this data by both **Product** and **Result**. However I don't want to show whole expirement (not only product) If It can't pass the filter.

I'm generating the query dynamically by a HTML form, I can select Product and the Result Number with it's value with a query like that.

```
Product C, Result5 > 1

SELECT * FROM exp WHERE ExpID IN 
(SELECT ExpID FROM exp WHERE Product = 'C' AND Result5 > 1) 
ORDER BY ExpID, Product ASC
```

This query works like a charm. However this query doesn't let me filter two product of same experience. Such as

```
Product C, Result5 > 1
Product F, Result5 > 0.2
```

While they are stored in different rows I can't find a proper way to do that. I want all the data of same Experiment in order, so I can't use `group by`. Last of all, there can be more than three product in an experiment, like C1, C2, C3...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. May be a better db design?

Comment: See normalzation. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Strawberry I know database table is not a spreadsheet. If could find a beter way, I would'nt be here, asking that.

Comment: So, a normalized table (if it was kept as just one table) might have four columns (exp_id*,product*,result_no*,value) *  = (component of) PRIMARY KEY. This normalized table would have ca. 20,000 rows.

Comment: @Strawberry As said in the question "Any help would be greatly appreciated. May be a better db design?". Now this is a helpful comment, thanks. Any other suggestions about my problem?

Comment: Once you rectify the design, any remaining problems will magically disappear.

Comment: @Strawberry So can you please give a query example for this situtation with such a table?

Comment: Provide the table (as a set of CREATE and INSERT statements) together with the desired result, and I'm sure someone will supply the query. I suggest you provide only a limited, but representative data set - 3, exp_ids, 2 products, and 4 results, say so approx. 20 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the first step would be to determine which experiment ID's are applicable.

Initially you used this:

```
SELECT ExpID
FROM exp 
WHERE Product = 'C' AND Result5 > 1
```

Now you want to these criteria

```
Product C, Result5 > 1
Product F, Result5 > 0.2
```

To get those experiment ID's:

```
SELECT ExpID
FROM exp 
WHERE (Product = 'C' AND Result5 > 1)
 OR (Product = 'F' AND Result5 > 0.2)
GROUP BY ExpID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The concept being, each experiment must be found exactly (i.e., the `HAVING` clause) the number of times of each OR criteria.

Ultimately your query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM exp 
WHERE ExpID IN 
  (SELECT ExpID
    FROM exp 
    WHERE (Product = 'C' AND Result5 > 1)
     OR (Product = 'F' AND Result5 > 0.2)
    GROUP BY ExpID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) 
ORDER BY ExpID, Product ASC
```

You may get better performance using this

```
SELECT exp.* 
FROM exp 
JOIN 
    (SELECT ExpID
     FROM exp 
     WHERE (Product = 'C' AND Result5 > 1)
       OR (Product = 'F' AND Result5 > 0.2)
     GROUP BY ExpID
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) AS temp
  ON exp.ExpID = temp.ExpID
ORDER BY exp.ExpID, exp.Product ASC
```